# Highcharts context menu causes chart to disappear on return from print screen only on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, charts, highcharts, contextmenu, corrupt

We are using Highcharts 4.0.4 and PHP as the server side script. There are multiple charts on a page and each chart has its context menu for print/save options.

The context menu works fine, but when control returns from the print screen to the page, the respective chart is either corrupted in size or disappears altogether.

**Strangely this bad behavior is observed only on Chrome but not IE.**

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ND5xf/1/) demonstrating this behavior.

```
Code along with fiddle
```

Any help or guidance on how to tackle this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaulty in the highcharts all elements are hidden apart of current chart. You can wrap the exporting function and dismiss this part of code.

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'print', function (proceed) {
        var chart = this,
            container = chart.container,
            origDisplay = [],
            win = window,
            origParent = container.parentNode,
            body = document.body,
            childNodes = body.childNodes;

        if (chart.isPrinting) { // block the button while in printing mode
            return;
        }

        chart.isPrinting = true;


        // print
        win.focus(); // #1510
        win.print();

        // allow the browser to prepare before reverting
        setTimeout(function () {

            // put the chart back in
            origParent.appendChild(container);


            chart.isPrinting = false;

        }, 1000);

    });
})(Highcharts);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ND5xf/5/

Comment: we overcame the issue by using % instead of px and resetting the window size(not sure if it was the way to go) . But looks like your solution is cleaner and apt, thanks.

Comment: Makes sense, all is up to you ;)